# FCM notifications not being sent with Spring

Tags: java, spring, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send notifications from my server made in Spring Boot with FCM. My client is made on Flutter.

```
@Service
public class ChatNotificationService implements IChatNotificationsService{
    @Override
    public void notify(User sender, User receiver) {
        Message msg = Message.builder()
                .setToken(receiver.getNotificationDeviceID())
                .putData("New message", "You have received a message from @" + sender.getUsername())
                .build();
        try{
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(msg);
        }catch (Exception e){
            //Handle exception...
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that it aparently works properly. But, the message never arrives to the device.

The message is build without errors and the `try` block is executed correctly too. It returns the expected ID sush as

> projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages/0:1500415314455276%31bd1c9631bd1c96

But the device doesn't receive any notification.

I've tried sending a message manually to **the same device registration token** with the Firebase dashboard and it works fine there. The device receives the notification as expected.
[image: Firebase dashboard]

It also works properly using postman directly

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA

{
   "message":{
      "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
      "notification":{
        "body":"This is an FCM notification message!",
        "title":"FCM Message"
      }
   }
}
```

This is my configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfiguration {
    @Bean
    FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging(FirebaseApp firebaseApp) {
        return FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp);
    }
    @Bean
    FirebaseApp firebaseApp(GoogleCredentials credentials) {
        FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .build();

        if(FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) { 
            return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        }else{
            return FirebaseApp.getInstance();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    GoogleCredentials googleCredentials() throws IOException {
       return GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new ClassPathResource("firebase-key.json").getInputStream());
    }

}
```

Other things i've tried:

- Testing on emulator and physical device
- Checked notifications settings were turned on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your configuration is correct, the message still needs a `body` to send.
You can add `body`, `title`, `image` via `Message.putData`. You're putting key `New message` which is not considered a `body`. Try this

```
Message msg = Message.builder()
    .setToken(receiver.getNotificationDeviceID())
    .putData("body", "You have received a message from @" + sender.getUsername())
    .build();
```

Also, you can do this

```
Message msg = Message.builder()
    .setToken(receiver.getNotificationDeviceID())
    .setNotification(Notification.builder()
        .setTitle("Some title")
        .setBody("You have received a message from @" + sender.getUsername())
    .build());
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've got the same problem with this code too :/

Comment: @LucasTomic hope it helps, is there any others issue with your code?

Comment: No. Just this. As I said in the post, the expected message (projects/myproject-b5ae1/...) is returned. However, it doesn't arrive any message to the device

Comment: I'm sorry, this answer is correct. I implemented it wrong. Thank you!